# create-react-native-app not working anymore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I'm still new to anything to do with expo and create-react-native-app. So here's my question. While learning react-native I've always used create-react-native-app to do so and it works fine, until one day, I did create-react-native-app and it showed an expo template this time. So I went along with the 'blank project' option. Then I run `npm run eject` as I would normally, but now I get a :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED exception.

Heres the exact prompt.

:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
E:\A_PhoneApps\Tests\CoolProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplication
  location: package com.facebook.react
E:\A_PhoneApps\Tests\CoolProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: package com.facebook.react
E:\A_PhoneApps\Tests\CoolProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
                                                            ^
  symbol: class ReactApplication
E:\A_PhoneApps\Tests\CoolProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
E:\A_PhoneApps\Tests\CoolProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
         ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
E:\A_PhoneApps\Tests\CoolProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainActivity.java:5: error: MainActivity is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPackages() in ReactActivity
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
       ^
E:\A_PhoneApps\Tests\CoolProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class ReactNativeHost
  location: class MainApplication
E:\A_PhoneApps\Tests\CoolProject\android\app\src\main\java\com\emptyprojecttemplate\MainApplication.java:35: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
8 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.001 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Now I have checked all the docs and went through the whole native code guide over and over again and I still can't fix it. I went into the projects package.json to see react-native' versions and it is set to:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz"
```

Before it would look like this:

```
"react-native": "~0.56.1"
```

I'm really really confused! what's happening here???

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall java jdk and make sure that JAVA_HOME environment variables are set correctly.

Comment: hm yeah I reinstalled jdk8 with --force and i've also checked and set JAVA_HOME environmen variables but still nothing... If this information helps, if i load an old project created with create-react-native-app, running react-native run-android still works...